# How to stop Jenkins from triggering a job unless the change is made to particular branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have Jenkins job setup for CI/CD purpose. I have configured the Jenkins job such that it gets automatically triggered by GitHub web hook.

Let us assume we have three branches `a,b & c`. I want the job to execute if and only if change is made to branch `b`. Any commit made to branches **a and c** should not trigger any job (at least job should abort without executing core logic). I have to use a jenkins ***pipeline*** project only. I am using declarative pipeline syntax for jenkins file.

There were 2 env variables available from Jenkins.

- GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT
- GIT_COMMIT

The code is as below

```
             steps {
                    if (${ env.GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT } == ${ env.GIT_COMMIT }) {
                    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                    currentBuild.description = 'This build was aborted because it was previously built on the same branch'
                    error('This build was aborted because it was previously built on the same branch')
                  }
            }
```

I tried doing a comparison and abort the build if git commit has already been built. I got the following error. *if* statement is Line 30.

```
WorkflowScript: 30: Expected a step @ line 30, column 21.
                       if (${ env.GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT } == ${ env.GIT_COMMIT }) {
                       ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:571)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:523)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:334)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:432)
Finished: FAILURE
```

GitHub webhook payload has a parameter called *ref* which tells which was changed made to. I am not sure how to access github payload. I am trying this in a corporate environment. I have restrictions on installing plugins. I am not sure how to get payload details from jenkins without extensions. Would appreciate if there was a way to solve this using code rather than a external based approach.

P.S : The following answers are for freestyle project, so don't mark mine as duplicate.

- [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440370/trigger-jenkins-job-when-pushing-to-a-particular-git-branch)
- [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349418/trigger-jenkins-job-only-when-changes-happen-to-a-particular-branch)

Thanks in advance!